# Project organization using Maven and ParameterSupplier

Tags: java, junit

I am wondering what would be some suggestions for project / module organization given the following situation:

1. I have a project `DomainObjects` in which I have a class `MyObject`

   1. In `/src/test/java` of `DomainObjects` I have the tests for `MyObject`
2. I have a project `Client` that depends on `DomainObjects`

I would like to add a `ParameterSupplier` called `MyObjectTestSupplier` class to provide test instances of `MyObject` for use by tests in `Client`.

It seems to make the most sense to provide `MyObjectTestSupplier` in the `DomainObjects` project. Here is my dilema...

1. if I put the supplier in `src/test/java` of `DomainObjects` it will not be available to `Client`.
2. I don't want to put it in `src/main/java` of `DomainObjects` because that means that JUnit would have to be included as a compile dependancy of `DomainObjects` and thereby be included in my production code.
3. if I put the supplier in some project `DomainObjectsTest` I have three options

   1. put just the supplier is the test project but this means that tests in `DomainObjects` could not use this supplier.
   2. put all the tests and suppliers for `DomainObjects` in `DomainObjectsTest` but that means that `DomainObjects` will be successfully compiled by maven even if tests fail
   3. copy the supplier in both `src/test/java` of `DomainObjects` and `src/main/java` of `DomainObjectsTest`.

I thought about trying to make `DomainObjectsTest` a module of `DomainObjects` but that only works if the packaging for `DomainObjects` is `pom` which does not work here.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

EDIT: As an explanation, `MyObject` is a simple bean (just getters and setters) and I use the `ParameterSuppier` pattern for providing populated instances of beans. The supplier provides utility methods to easily create populated instances of the bean for use in testing. I do this so that I don't repeat this population code (or the mocking equivilent) throughout my project(s).

Comment: What about creating `MyObjectTestSupplier` in the `DomainObjects` project's `src/test/java` code base, publishing the `DomainObjects-X.Y-tests` artifact to your local Maven repository and specifying a test-scoped dependency on this in your `Client` project? [As explained in the official mini guide on this particular topic.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html)

Comment: @KohányiRóbert I will try that out! Thanks! If it works please consider publishing this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert Thank you! That indeed worked. Since you posted first I would like to give you credit if you will repost as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the official Maven mini guide on this particular topic](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) says you should publish a test artifact of the `DomainObjects` project into your local Maven repository (or anywhere you'd like or able to) and use the `DomainObjects-X.Y-tests` artifact as a test-scoped dependency in your `Client` project.

Publishing a test artifact is done by using [the *jar:test-jar* goal of the Maven JAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html).

If you include this artifact as a test-scoped dependency in your `Client` project then any other project that depends on the `Client` project won't inherit your `DomainObjects` project's test artifact, because *test-scoped dependencies are not transitive* by default as stated by [the official guide on Maven's dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Answer (score 1):

That is a bad design example what you're describing. Your unit test can't depend on external dependencies to be "unit".

What you need to do is to mock all dependencies and test only `Client` code. Use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or another library of your choice to create mock instances of `MyObject` in client project according to what you expect this class to do. Test `MyObject` behavior in its own project - `DomainObjects`.

In mockito creating a mock is just :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
...
MyObject myMock = mock(MyObject.class);
when(myMock.doWhatYouNeed(params)).thenReturn(whatYouExpect);
```

**Edit:**

Another ideas

Publish DomainObjects' tests as artifact of type `test-jar` as descibed [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) and use it as test-scoped dependency in Client. But this is quite ugly...

Nice design is :

- `DomainObjectAPI` project with `MyObject`,
- `DomainObjectTestSupplier` using `DomainObjectAPI` providing suppliers,
- `DomainObject` using `DomainObjectAPI` for compile and `DomainObjectTestSupplier` for testing
- `Client` using `DomainObjectAPI`, `DomainObject` for compile and `DomainObjectTestSupplier` for testing.

It's just an overkill.

Comment: I added an edit to explain a bit further. I don't believe in mocking simple bean classes. It is just as easy to simply populate them as needed. However, I have found over time that I end up repeating this population code over and over again. This is what led me to start using the supplier pattern. As my project(s) have become larger I have started breaking them into modules but I don't want to give up the usefullness of the supplier pattern. Finally, providing instances of beans for testing is the point of JUnit's ParameterSupplier.

Comment: So the  solution is to publish DomainObjects' tests as artifact of type `test-jar` as descibed [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) and use it as test-scoped dependency in Client. But this is quite ugly...

Comment: +1 for `test-jar` That does indeed work. Interesting difference of opinion, I think it is beautiful.

Comment: It is ugly because project B depends on a bunch of test from project A but actually don't need them. If project's A tests will depend on C, then A will depend on C too. The design is ugly, but useful of course.